# Error from "Not-So-Special" Characters in .NET Windows Service .config file

Tags: .net, xml, service, app-config

**TLDR;** Some not-so-special characters in .config file prevent my .NET Windows Service from starting until after

1. removing the chars
2. starting the service
3. stopping the service
4. adding the chars back
5. starting the service again

Special chars have already been escaped at this point, so the remaining chars are not special.

---

I'm sorry this turned into such a long post.  I'm going crazy thinking about this!

I recently added an appSetting to the config file of a Windows Service that has been running for many years. The setting identifies which character to use as a symbol in a report when certain scenarios are encountered.
Originally, the new setting looked like this:

```
<add key="symbol" value="×"/>
```

**Note that that is the multiplication symbol (which can also be represented in HTML by &#215; or &times;) -  not a lowercase x.**

This worked in my local testing (Windows 10 box), but when I put it out to the server, I got differing results.  On the server, I updated the .config file with this new setting and updated the code to use it, and started the service back up, but it fails to start with the following message in the Event Log:

Source: .NET Runtime

> Application: myServiceName.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException

I was surprised that it didnt like the ×, b/c that shouldnt break XML, but I've had to escape characters before in .config files, so I swapped out the setting to look like this:

```
<add key="symbol" value="&times;"/>
```

Saved the .config and attempted to start the service, but got a different error:

Source: SideBySide

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\myPath\myServiceName.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\myPath\myServiceName.exe.Config" on line 104. Invalid Xml syntax.

Huh?
I know there's no error in the XML syntax, the service has been running for years.  There is 1 new line in that file, and it is the new appSetting I showed above.
Grasping at straws, I Ctrl-X that new appSetting from the .config file, save, and start the service - and it starts successfully. Ok, that was expected, and shows there's nothing else wrong with the XML.  Stop the Service, Ctrl-V that key back into the file at the same place where it was removed.  Save, and start the service - and **it starts successfully**!!

What the hell?

So the service runs correctly with the new appSetting using the &times; value for several days until I need to reboot the server.  When the server is rebooted, the service will not start and gives the same SideBySide error listed above.

Through my testing, this now happens every time I reboot.  The service WILL NOT start until I remove (or comment out) the line that has the &times; from the .config file.

After I edit the .config file, the service will start correctly - but it needs the new key...  So I stop the service, add the key back to the .config file, and the service starts correctly - this time with the key that I need.  After this point, the service can be stopped/started repeatedly and always works until the next reboot when I have to go through the process again.

What. The. Hell.

If the × character is a special character for XML or .config files, it is not documented anywhere that I can see.  But even if it is, I escaped that character, and my service still refuses to start until after I remove it from the config file.  After it starts without it, I can add it back and it starts correctly.

Anyone experienced anything like this before??

I know I could just try a different symbol, but what is going on?  Why would this fail?  And if it fails, why will it run successfully after removing and adding it back?

Comment: `new XmlDocument().LoadXml(@"<add key=""symbol"" value=""&#215;""/>");` works for me and gives the correct character, have you tried that XML syntax? Also, which build of .NET are you using?

Comment: Interesting - yes, "&#215;" also works for me.  However, in this case, I need to be able to put the symbol in an Excel report, so whether I use "&times;" or "&#215;", or "somePlaceholder", I have to replace that value in the code with the actual symbol before I can use it.  
Thank you for pointing out a workaround.  After starting with the value "&#215;" I can change that value to anything else and it start/stops correctly.  Also the service starts correctly after reboot with that value.
The service is built with .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: No what I meant to say is that once loaded with `ConfigurationManager`, with that syntax it it should have the correct value already, the `×`. Does it not?

Comment: I didnt even consider that..  Yes, when the config value is loaded from the Hex code, it converts that automatically to the symbol I'm wanting.  I was not aware it would even attempt that.  I thought those key/value pairs were always picked up as plain text.  This does not explain why the symbol or the HTML entity name throws an error until the service starts without it, but it is a solid workaround.  Thank you!!

Comment: It clearly needs to be valid XHTML. But yeah, that is how to escape the character, so the deserializer will of course get the correct one. Not sure why `&times;` doesn't work